# print line from console to the GUI textbox/lebel

Tags: java, javafx, printing, textbox, console

I'm trying to build user interface for my automatic test in webdriver.

My question how can I print all the console line in the label or textbox ?

Method set on the button:

```
    public void AutologinTest(ActionEvent event){
    try {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process pr = rt.exec("C:\\lottotest2\\workspace\\Lotteryscript\\Autologin.bat");
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(line);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code, instead of posting a screenshot of it.

Comment: It is unclear what you want to do. If you are creating a user interface, it should either use the console for I/O, or a GUI for I/O, but not both.

Comment: If you don't want it in the console, don't use `System.out.println` (which sends something to the console). Just append the text to whatever control you are referring to. A `TextArea` is probably the most natural thing to use.

Comment: i tried to write `lebel.setText(line); ` instead of `System.out.println`
but in the lebel it present only one line  of many

Comment: Why not do `lebel.setText(lebel.getText()+"\n"+line);`?? Or, if it is a `TextArea`, just do `lebel.appendText("\n"+line);`?

Comment: lol before i see your comment i "discovered that "appendText" work by mayself 
, why i didn't use it ? because i didn't know lol
THX YOU

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.setOut(PrintStream stream):

```
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(
    new OutputStream() {
        public void write(int c){
            myLabel.setText(myLabel.getText() + (char) c);
        }
    }
);

System.setOut(ps);

System.out.println("Hello!"); // will print on the label
```

Comment: This is an extremely roundabout way of appending text to a control. Why use `System.out.println(...)` at all????

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to redirect `STDOUT` to `TextArea` or other control:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.PrintStream;

public class Main22 extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        TextArea textArea = new TextArea();

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(textArea));
        primaryStage.show();

        System.setOut(new PrintStream(System.out) {
            @Override
            public void write(byte[] buf, int off, int len) {
                super.write(buf, off, len);

                String msg = new String(buf, off, len);

                textArea.setText(textArea.getText() + msg);
            }
        });

        System.out.println("bla-bla-bla");
        System.out.println("Yet one line!");
    }
}
```

As you can see I just override `write` method of `PrintStream` and append incoming text message for text in `TextArea`.

[image: screenshot of application]

FYI: I don't recommend to use `TextArea` for display logs because it have very poor performance when trying to process large text.